# How to get indices of a specific number in an array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to pick the indices of number 8 without knowing its position in the array.

```
a = np.arange(10)
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I tried np.where,np.argwhere. but it didn't work

Comment: I know how to get a value corresponding to particular index but here I have to get index corresponding to particular value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where` like :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,4,8,2,6,7,9,8,7,8,8,9,1,0])
>>> a
array([1, 4, 8, 2, 6, 7, 9, 8, 7, 8, 8, 9, 1, 0])
>>> np.where(a==8)[0]
array([ 2,  7,  9, 10], dtype=int64)
```